# SDL Tridion Ambient Data Framework HTTP Requests

Tags: tridion

I'm seeing my Ambient Data Framework code is entered on every http request, so if a page has 5 images, the one webpage is running the code 6 times.

Is there an easy way to run the code only when the page (aspx) is requested?

I'm running on Tridion 2009, IIS 7 and .Net 4.0

Thanks

John

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make sure the Ambient Data Framework module only runs for ASP.NET requests, by simply ticking the box that says 'Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers' in the Modules section of IIS.

You can also exclude certain URLs from being handled by the framework by editing the configuration file. See the following page in the documentation: [Excluding paths from the Ambient Data Framework filter](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_32C65FFE08454808B577B5E8679CA5A6)

Comment: I didn't know that, but it's very useful.

Comment: Just a note that the link to the 'Excluding paths...' seems to be a 2011 feature only.  The IIS item resolved the issue.